# BuddyPress bbPress unique thread per member

Tags: buddypress, bbpress

I would like a discussion about each user in one place. Is it possible to automatically assign a unique bbPress thread for each user and have a link to that thread placed in the BuddyPress profile?

my current attempt is to add the following code to the functions.php:

```
function automatic_user_forum( $user_id ) {
if( !$user_id ) return false;
$post = array(
‘post_title’ => ‘My forum’,
‘post_content’ => ‘This is a forum.’,
‘post_name’ => ‘my-forum’,
‘post_status’ => ‘publish’,
‘post_type’ => ‘forum’,
);
$post_id = wp_insert_post($post);
}
add_action( ‘bp_core_activated_user’, ‘automatic_user_forum’ );
```

However, it is not working and the site crashes. Any help?

Alternatively I tried the following which doesn't crash but also doesnt create any forum. Whats wrong?

```
<?php
function bbp_insert_girl_forum() {
$forum_data = array(
        'post_parent'    => 0, // forum ID
        'post_content'   => 'Nullam est felis, tempor luctus consequat a, aliquam ut dolor. Proin euismod aliquam ante accumsan cursus. Morbi ornare eros magna, eget sollicitudin turpis fringilla quis. Proin vitae vehicula felis. Fusce non lacus consequat, faucibus nisl sed, consequat dolor.',
        'post_title'     => 'Test Forum: Loads of Topics for topic Pagination',
    );
    if(function_exists('bbp_insert_forum')) {
        $forum_id = bbp_insert_forum( $forum_data );
    }else {
        print "insert forum not defined";
            }

        $topic_data = array(
            'post_parent'    => $forum_id, // forum ID
            'post_content'   => 'Proin euismod aliquam ante accumsan cursus. Morbi ornare eros magna, eget sollicitudin turpis fringilla quis. Proin vitae vehicula felis. Fusce non lacus consequat, faucibus nisl sed, consequat dolor.',
            'post_title'     => 'Gravida facilisis eleifend',
        );
        if(function_exists('bbp_insert_topic')) {
            $topic_id = bbp_insert_topic( $topic_data );
        }
                else {
                print "insert topic not defined";
                    }
}
add_action( ‘bp_core_activated_user’, ‘bbp_insert_girl_forum’ );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function bbp_insert_girl_forum() {
$forum_data = array(
    'post_parent'    => 0, // forum ID
    'post_content'   => 'Nullam ...',
    'post_title'     => 'Test Forum',
);
if(function_exists('bbp_insert_forum')) {
    $forum_id = bbp_insert_forum( $forum_data );
}
}
add_action( 'bp_core_activated_user', 'bbp_insert_girl_forum' );
```